# How to change .CSV language format

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a `CSV` in which the data is in English format and now I want to change the data into **another language format**(especially Urdu language ). When I save the file after changing the format it goes through this warning

### Some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as a CSV (comma-delimited) file. Do you want to continue with the selected format?

When i reopen the file after saving then those cells are then filled with `?????????` words, and in other spreadsheet software those same cells become blank.

**How can I save CSV successfully with the different formats?**

Comment: Suggest trying https://finworks.biz/faq/how-to-include-foreign-language-characters-in-a-csv-import-file/

Comment: CSV is pure data. If you want formatting, don't use CSV, use a worksheet file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue long time ago. As far as I know, saving just as CSV uses default settings. In my case this worked for me:

1. Click on *Save as*
2. Choose CSV and click on *tools* --> *web options*
3. In the *encoding* tab, choose your right encoding.

[image]